# How does pandas dataframe.to_gqb upload to the remote Table?

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

Is the `pandas` `dataframe.to_gbq()` function something that Bulk loads to a table or inserts to a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "bulk load" and "inserts" but the whole code for this method you can find [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py#L947).

As you can see, `to_gbq` method receives as one of its inputs a `chunksize` whose default value is 10.000. Then it instantiates a [BigQuery Connector](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py#L190) to run the load operation.

In the `load_data` method, you can see that it [evaluates](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py#L622) if the rows list is of size *chunksize* and if it is, then it proceeds to run a stream insert by calling `service.tabledata().insertAll()`.

Therefore, it does insert data to BigQuery by chunks of data and it does so by calling the streaming method `insertAll()`.